# How to click on a link with no ID or Name?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, angularjs-ng-href

HTML code:

```
<a ng-repeat="group in groups()" ng-href="phones/Apple/iPhone%203G%20or%203GS/" class="ng-scope" href="phones/Apple/iPhone%203G%20or%203GS/">
        <div class="card-box device-box">
            <span class="card-text ng-binding">iPhone 3G or 3GS</span>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right visible-xs"></i>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

C# code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("IPHONE 3G 16GB")).Click();
```

Comment: So you provided the HTML and the code but didn't state what the problem is. I'm assuming that code doesn't work... what's the result? Please provide more details.

Comment: Will By.LinkText work? The tag you are referencing is not an A tag (link).

Answer (score 1):

I would make an XPath expression here to find the `a` element that has a `span` element inside having `iPhone 3G or 3GS` text:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[div/span = 'iPhone 3G or 3GS']")).Click();
```

You may also try approaching it with `PartialLinkText` locator instead:

```
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("IPHONE 3G 16GB")).Click();
```

Comment: @Blanc nice, what do you mean by "does not work"? Any errors?

Comment: I also recommend finding the element by XPath. Getting the path right isn't always the most straightforward, but there are some handy features in Chrome and FireFox (plugins as well) that will let you get an element's XPath which you can then use in your code.

Comment: @alecxe.: I am getting element not found when I use driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[div/span = 'iPhone 3G or 3GS']")).Click();

Answer (score 0):

Try with below xpath

```
By.XPath("//a//span[text()='iPhone 3G or 3GS']")
```